# How to get request a specific ID from Database in a C# .net API

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm looking to get a row in my database by a ID or value. At the moment i've tried a few ways and haven't found a solution yet.

This method returns all customers, what do i need to do to modify the below to return 1 Customer by the id i provide to the method. Or what other method can i use to do this.

```
// GET: api/Customer/5
    [Route("api/Customer/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CustomerReqDTO))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        var customer = db.Customers.Include(c => c.customer_id).Select(c =>
        new CustomerReqDTO()
        {
            customer_id = c.customer_id,
            first_name = c.first_name,
            last_name = c.last_name,
            email = c.email,
            username = c.username


        });    
        
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(customer);
    }
```

I've also tried using this approach but for my bookings object:

```
// GET: api/Bookings/5
    [Route("api/Bookings/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(BookingDTO))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBooking(int id)
    {
        

        var bookingTest = from b in db.Bookings
                   where b.booking_id.Equals(id)
                   select b;

        if (bookingTest == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(bookingTest);

    }
```

Comment: Remove Include and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to filter your result is `Where`. You could do something like this

```
var customer = db.Customers
    .Where(c => c.customer_id == id)
    .Select(c => new CustomerReqDTO()
    {
        customer_id = c.customer_id,
        first_name = c.first_name,
        last_name = c.last_name,
        email = c.email,
        username = c.username


    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

You might want to consider to convert your controller to `async` to make a more efficient use of thread pool, then you could use the `async` version of `FirstOrDefault`

```
var customer = await db.Customers
    .Where(c => c.customer_id == id)
    .Select(c => new CustomerReqDTO()
    {
        customer_id = c.customer_id,
        first_name = c.first_name,
        last_name = c.last_name,
        email = c.email,
        username = c.username


    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Likely you're not going to gain where much converting this particular query to async but definitively you should keep it in mind as it brings real advantages when heavy queries are executed.